# Intellij show possible merge conflicts before actual merge

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a file that was changed in one branch and renamed in another (but from comparison perspective it was deleted). I use IntelliJ for merging. When I merge the branch where the file was changed into the one where it was deleted, in the merge window the IntelliJ shows two panels one for the deleted file which is obviously empty and the other one for modified file with changes highlighted in darker pink.

I need to add these changes to my renamed file. And I can do it manually, np, however I cannot keep the merge/comparison window open. It must be closed before I can do any code modifications.

My question is: is there a way to get the same kind of comparison with possible merge conflicts highlighted before the actual merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ relies on the command-line git and needs git to attempt the merge before it can show you the merge dialog. So, unfortunately, it is not possible to get the merge dialog without starting the merge.

However, it seems that to solve the task you only need the merge dialog to be non-modal - here is the request for it in JetBrains tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66552

Comment: Thank you. According to the link you provided, this feature has been sitting in the asks for 7 years to no avail. However with the latest update (which I installed today), if I cancel out of merge window and go to Version Control tab down by the status bar and expand Default Changes, there is now a new sub menu called Merge Conflicts and it is not modal anymore!

Comment: The Merge Conflicts node has been added last year. But clicking it still opens a modal dialog, and the 3-pane merge is still modal. There are plans to address this eventually, but no ETA

Answer (score 0):

Using version IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition), I am able to open a merge non-modally by:

1. When the merge dialog appears, click Cancel
2. Open the Git view
3. Click on a changed file in the Local Changes tab.

   - This initially shows the merge diff in the side pane of the Git view.
4. To open the merge diff in the main editor area, right-click on the file (in the Local Changes tab) and select "Show Diff".

   - This will open the merge diff in the main editor area.